# Configure printer on WAN port

Tags: linux, router, dns, firewall, network-printer

I have a network where router 1 is connected to Internet and has a network printer. Router 1 is a home router with default settings. A second router (router 2) is connected to router 1 on it's wan port. Router 2 is running Linux (tomatoUSB) configured for masquerading and is using opendns. I want the computer behind router 2 to be able to print.

Here's a schema of the network:

`(192.168.1.0/24)          (192.168.2.0/24)
Internet -- Router 1 ---------------- Router 2 ---------------- computer
                             |
                          printer`

The printer is a Canon mx510, it's URI is detected as dnssd://Canon%20MX510%20series._ipp._tcp.local/ . So I guess it use dnssd to advertise itself and ipp for printing ?

- What should I change to the firewall to let computers behind router 2 print ?
- Is there anything else I need to change in the network ?

Edit:
I can actually ping, access the web interface, nmap the printer from computer. I can see ports 631 (ipp) is open. I can telnet to it, but I the computer cannot find the printer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are already a step ahead because you have tomato running on Router 2.

Essentially, when a router routes traffic they have a routing list. This network lies behind this interface, this network lies behind this one.

Normal routers only have to deal with two networks. Internal, and external (often called the "default route).

You'll have to log on to the terminal of tomato and tell it that there is a network that *isnt* the internet behind the wan port - to do this you'll have to use the iptables command.

The command will probably look something like this - `ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0`

eth0 will have to be replaced with the name of of your WAN port. The command `ifconfig` will give you more information about this.

Comment: I guess iptables will be useful to let some traffic through, but which port ? 192.168.1.0/24 is already in my routing table.